# Why does the drawing path's stroke become warped with device rotation animation

Tags: ios, uiview

What causes the path's stroke to become warped as the device rotation animation takes place? What are some ways to keep it from happening?

Just before the animation starts, the path looks like it was drawn with a calligraphy pen, then by the time the rotation finishes it looks normal again.

[image]

**Drawing View**

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let strokeW: CGFloat = 10

        let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: strokeW/2, dy: strokeW/2))
        path.lineWidth = strokeW
        path.stroke()

        path.move(to: center)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func setPriority(_ priority: UILayoutPriority) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        self.priority = priority
        return self
    }
}

extension UILayoutPriority {
    static var high: UILayoutPriority {
        return UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 751)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var drawingView = DrawingView()

    var safeArea = UILayoutGuide()
    var lg = UILayoutGuide()
    var wConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var hConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        drawingView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        self.view.addSubview(drawingView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.drawingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        applyConstraints()
        updateOrientation()
    }

    func updateOrientation() {
        if self.view.bounds.width < self.view.bounds.height {
            self.wConstraint.constant = 180
            self.hConstraint.constant = 320
        } else {
            self.wConstraint.constant = 320
            self.hConstraint.constant = 180
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {_ in

            self.updateOrientation()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.drawingView.setNeedsDisplay()
        })
    }

    func applyConstraints() {

        safeArea = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        self.view.addLayoutGuide(lg)

        wConstraint = lg.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180)
        hConstraint = lg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([wConstraint, hConstraint])

        // layout guide constraints
        let lgConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = ([
            lg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.centerXAnchor),
            lg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.centerYAnchor),
            lg.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            lg.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            lg.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            lg.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),

            lg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).setPriority(.high),
            lg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).setPriority(.high),
            lg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 10).setPriority(.high),
            lg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).setPriority(.high),
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(lgConstraints)

        // drawingView constraints
        let drawingViewConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = ([
            drawingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            drawingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            drawingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            drawingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(drawingViewConstraints)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIView's default contentMode property is `.scaleToFill`

Changing it to `.scaleAspectFit` prevents the stroke's width from being distorted.

I set `self.drawingView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` in `loadView()` from the question's example code to get this result.

[image]